# CSS position of element not moving

Tags: css

Our Flash game development portfolio can be seen here:
http://www.letsdesign.co.uk/index.html

Here is the CSS style sheet for the design: 
http://www.letsdesign.co.uk/rw_common/themes/a_viator/styles.css

Please look at the News Ticker, it's slightly too low and need to be moved up 5 pixels. 
I am unable to find a place to alter the position of this element (also known as extraContainer2).

Does anyone know what is making it appear like this and how I can shift the news ticker text up a bit?

Thanks in advance for all you help,

Comment: i see no problem on chrome18, linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `.alignNav` is too high

```
.alignNav {
     text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 6px;
    height: 110px;
}
```

Setting its height to 100px, or giving extraContainer2 relative positioning with negative top will fix the problem

```
#extraContainer2
{
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to alter this part:

```
.alignNav {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 6px;
  height: 105px;
}
```

height has been 110px before.